# Why did I encounter an "Error syncing pod" with Dataflow pipeline?

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-dataflow

I experiment a weird error with my Dataflow pipeline when I want to use specific library from PyPI.

I need `jsonschema` in a ParDo, so, in my `requirements.txt`file, I added `jsonschema==3.2.0`. 
I launch my pipeline with the command line below:

```sh
python -m gcs_to_all \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project <my-project-id> \
    --region europe-west1 \
    --temp_location gs://<my-bucket-name>/temp/ \
    --input_topic "projects/<my-project-id>/topics/<my-topic>" \
    --network=<my-network> \
    --subnetwork=<my-subnet> \
    --requirements_file=requirements.txt \
    --experiments=allow_non_updatable_job \
    --streaming
```

In the terminal, all seems to be good:

```sh
INFO:root:2020-01-03T09:18:35.569Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Worker configuration: n1-standard-4 in europe-west1-b.
INFO:root:2020-01-03T09:18:35.806Z: JOB_MESSAGE_WARNING: The network default doesn't have rules that open TCP ports 12345-12346 for internal connection with other VMs. Only rules with a target tag 'dataflow' or empty target tags set apply. If you don't specify such a rule, any pipeline with more than one worker that shuffles data will hang. Causes: Firewall rules associated with your network don't open TCP ports 12345-12346 for Dataflow instances. If a firewall rule opens connection in these ports, ensure target tags aren't specified, or that the rule includes the tag 'dataflow'.
INFO:root:2020-01-03T09:18:48.549Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
```

Where's no error in the log tab on Dataflow webpage, but in stackdriver:

```
message: "Error syncing pod 6515c378c6bed37a2c0eec1fcfea300c ("<dataflow-id>--01030117-c9pc-harness-5lkv_default(6515c378c6bed37a2c0eec1fcfea300c)"), skipping: [failed to "StartContainer" for "sdk0" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=sdk0 pod=<dataflow-id>--01030117-c9pc-harness-5lkv_default(6515c378c6bed37a2c0eec1fcfea300c)""
message: ", failed to "StartContainer" for "sdk1" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=sdk1 pod=<dataflow-id>--01030117-c9pc-harness-5lkv_default(6515c378c6bed37a2c0eec1fcfea300c)"" 
message: ", failed to "StartContainer" for "sdk2" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=sdk2 pod=<dataflow-id>--01030117-c9pc-harness-5lkv_default(6515c378c6bed37a2c0eec1fcfea300c)"" 
message: ", failed to "StartContainer" for "sdk3" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=sdk3 pod=<dataflow-id>--01030117-c9pc-harness-5lkv_default(6515c378c6bed37a2c0eec1fcfea300c)""
```

I find this error too (in info mode):

```
Collecting jsonschema (from -r /var/opt/google/staged/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Installing build dependencies: started
Looking in links: /var/opt/google/staged
  Installing build dependencies: started
Collecting jsonschema (from -r /var/opt/google/staged/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Installing build dependencies: started
Looking in links: /var/opt/google/staged
Collecting jsonschema (from -r /var/opt/google/staged/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-mdurhav9/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links /var/opt/google/staged -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (5 lines):
  Looking in links: /var/opt/google/staged
  Collecting setuptools>=40.6.0
  Collecting wheel
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
```

But I don't know why it can get this dependency...

Do you have any idea how I can debug this? or why I encounter this error?

Thanks

Comment: There is a playbook for this error: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#error-syncing-pod

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Dataflow workers start, they execute several steps:

1. Install packages from `requirements.txt`
2. Install packages  specified as `extra_packages`
3. Install workflow tarball and execute actions provided in `setup.py`.

`Error syncing pod` with `CrashLoopBackOff` message can be related to dependency conflict. You need to verify that there are no conflicts with the libraries and versions used for the job. Please refer to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies) for staging required dependencies of the pipeline.

Also, take a look for [preinstalled dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#sdk-for-python) and this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54073000/9398998).

What you can try is change the version of `jsonschema` and try run it again. If it wouldn't help, please provide `requirements.txt` file.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, 
I removed all dependencies in my  `requirements.txt` except for `jsonschema`. I also have to downgrade the version of this lib but the pipeline works well !