# How to properly load non-PyPi dependencies in GCP Dataflow using Beam Python SDK?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Dataflow job is dependent on a private Python library written by our Data Science team. DirectRunner works fine (per usual), but it hangs when I run the job on DataflowRunner.

I have followed the instructions found in the [Apache documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) which are:

1. Create a tarball of the library
2. Running the pipeline with the `extra-package` argument

The problem is that then the Dataflow job just hangs with no error. I've added logs in the files that my Dataflow job utilizes, but it doesn't even get to that point.

The logs show that there is an error of

```
"Error syncing pod e7943dc18f1ef06fe3ee759c73b86394 ("dataflow-kimbreakingstuff-12021212-0oqm-harness-wx63_default(e7943dc18f1ef06fe3ee759c73b86394)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "python" with CrashLoopBackOff: "back-off 20s restarting failed container=python pod=dataflow-kimbreakingstuff-12021212-0oqm-harness-wx63_default(e7943dc18f1ef06fe3ee759c73b86394)""
```

My question is how do I properly load this non-PyPi module into the Dataflow workers?

Here is my dataflow `main.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...

    argv = [
        "--runner=DataflowRunner",
        "--job_name=kimbreakingstuff",
        "--save_main_session",
        "--project={0}".format(PROJECT),
        "--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/".format(BUCKET),
        "--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/".format(BUCKET),
        "--region=us-central1",
        "--subnetwork=regions/us-central1/subnetworks/development",
        "--setup_file=./setup.py",
        "--extra_packages=dist/elmo-1.0.tar.gz"
    ]
    with beam.Pipeline(argv=argv) as p:
        twitter_base.run(p)
```

Comment: could you open logging (from the DF job page, open logging in StackDriver), and look at worker-startup logs? These should show what has happened while workers are starting up. You should see a failure to build a python wheel, or to install the extra package. LMK if that doesn't work and we can try something else.

Comment: Sure, the logs show it was installed

Comment: In fact, I don't see any errors on the workers or worker-startup. Its only on the Kubernetes resource

Comment: Can you please check on the dependencies of your DF job? I found this related SO related [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59579065/9398998) which may be similar to your case. It dealt with dependency conflicts in their DF job.

Comment: Ah yes. I see that my external non-PyPi library has a dependency conflict. Should I just pin the versions to what is stated in the docs?

Comment: Yes, you may try to do that approach to resolve the dependency issue. And then, please try running the job again.

Comment: then, if you can, please add what you did as an answer, so others can use it (and upvote it ;))