# ModuleNotFoundError in Dataflow job

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam

I am trying to execute a apache beam pipeline as a dataflow job in Google Cloud Platform.

My project structure is as follows:

```
root_dir/
  __init__.py
  ​setup.py
  ​main.py
  ​utils/
    __init__.py
    log_util.py
    config_util.py
```

Here's my setup.py

```py
setuptools.setup(
   name='dataflow_example',
   version='1.0',
   install_requires=[
        "google-cloud-tasks==2.2.0",
        "google-cloud-pubsub>=0.1.0",
        "google-cloud-storage==1.39.0",
        "google-cloud-bigquery==2.6.2",
        "google-cloud-secret-manager==2.0.0",
        "google-api-python-client==2.3.0",
        "oauth2client==4.1.3",
        "apache-beam[gcp]>=2.20.0",
        "wheel>=0.36.2"
   ],
   packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

Here's my pipeline code:

```
import math
import apache_beam as beam

from datetime import datetime
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

from utils.log_util import LogUtil
from utils.config_util import ConfigUtil


class DataflowExample:
    config = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigUtil.get_config(module_config=["config"])
        self.project = self.config['project']
        self.region = self.config['location']
        self.bucket = self.config['core_bucket']
        self.batch_size = 10

    def execute_pipeline(self):
        try:
            LogUtil.log_n_notify(log_type="info", msg=f"Dataflow started")

            query = "SELECT id, name, company FROM `<bigquery_table>` LIMIT 10"

            beam_options = {
                "project": self.project,
                "region": self.region,
                "job_name": "dataflow_example",
                "runner": "DataflowRunner",
                "temp_location": f"gs://{self.bucket}/temp_location/"
            }

            options = PipelineOptions(**beam_options, save_main_session=True)

            with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
                data = (
                        pipeline
                        | 'Read from BQ ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=query, use_standard_sql=True))
                        | 'Count records' >> beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
                        | 'Print ' >> beam.ParDo(PrintCount(), self.batch_size)
                )

            LogUtil.log_n_notify(log_type="info", msg=f"Dataflow completed")
        except Exception as e:
            LogUtil.log_n_notify(log_type="error", msg=f"Exception in execute_pipeline - {str(e)}")


class PrintCount(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = LogUtil()

    def process(self, row_count, batch_size):
        try:
            current_date = datetime.today().date()
            total = int(math.ceil(row_count / batch_size))

            self.logger.log_n_notify(log_type="info", msg=f"Records pulled from table on {current_date} is {row_count}")

            self.logger.log_n_notify(log_type="info", msg=f"Records per batch: {batch_size}. Total batches: {total}")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.log_n_notify(log_type="error", msg=f"Exception in PrintCount.process  - {str(e)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df_example = DataflowExample()
    df_example.execute_pipeline()
```

Functionality of pipeline is

1. Query against BigQuery Table.
2. Count the total records fetched from querying.
3. Print using the custom Log module present in utils folder.

I am running the job using cloud shell using `command - python3 - main.py`

Though the Dataflow job starts, the worker nodes throws error after few mins saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'"

"utils" folder is available and the same code works fine when executed with "DirectRunner".

`log_util` and `config_util` files are custom util files for logging and config fetching respectively.

Also, I tried running with `setup_file` options as `python3 - main.py --setup_file </path/of/setup.py>` which makes the job to just freeze and does not proceed even after 15 mins.

How do I resolve the ModuleNotFoundError with "DataflowRunner"?

Comment: I mimicked your file structure, encountered the `ModuleNotFoundError` when doing only `python main.py`. But it worked for me after adding `--setup_file`. What does the job logs say when doing `python3 -m main.py --setup_file </path/of/setup.py>`? Can you edit your post and include relevant the logs?

Comment: @RiccoD: Error noticed when setup_file is passed : "Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "python" with CrashLoopBackOff"

Understood that something w.r.to Apache Beam SDK version is causing the error after seeing this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117053/google-cloud-dataflow-stuck

I removed the "apache-beam[gcp]>=2.20.0" from the install_requires of setup.py file and it is working fine.

Comment: @RiccoD - I am passing the setup file as beam_options = {
                "project": self.project,
                "region": self.region,
                "job_name": "dataflow_example",
                "runner": "DataflowRunner",
                "temp_location": f"gs://{self.bucket}/temp_location/",
    "setup_file": "./setup.py"
            }

Comment: @RiccoD - If I execute by adding "apache-beam[gcp]>=2.20.0" in setup.py, I see error from workers "Beam SDK base version 2.32.0 does not match Dataflow Python worker version 2.28.0. Please check Dataflow worker startup logs and make sure that correct version of Beam SDK is installed"

Comment: You can post this as an answer and accept it, so the solution is visible and will help others who encounter this problem in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as community wiki. As confirmed by @GopinathS the error and fix are as follows:

The error encountered by the workers is `Beam SDK base version 2.32.0 does not match Dataflow Python worker version 2.28.0. Please check Dataflow worker startup logs and make sure that correct version of Beam SDK is installed`.

To fix this **"apache-beam[gcp]>=2.20.0" is removed** from `install_requires` of setup.py since, the **'>='** is assigning the latest available version (2.32.0 as of this writing) while the workers version are only 2.28.0.

Updated setup.py:

```
setuptools.setup(
   name='dataflow_example',
   version='1.0',
   install_requires=[
        "google-cloud-tasks==2.2.0",
        "google-cloud-pubsub>=0.1.0",
        "google-cloud-storage==1.39.0",
        "google-cloud-bigquery==2.6.2",
        "google-cloud-secret-manager==2.0.0",
        "google-api-python-client==2.3.0",
        "oauth2client==4.1.3", # removed apache-beam[gcp]>=2.20.0
        "wheel>=0.36.2"
   ],
   packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

Updated `beam_options` in the pipeline code:

```
    beam_options = {
        "project": self.project,
        "region": self.region,
        "job_name": "dataflow_example",
        "runner": "DataflowRunner",
        "temp_location": f"gs://{self.bucket}/temp_location/",
        "setup_file": "./setup.py"
    }
```

Also make sure that you pass all the pipeline options at once and not partially.

If you pass `--setup_file </path/of/setup.py>` in the command then make sure to read and append the setup file path into the already defined `beam_options` variable using `argument_parser` in your code.

To avoid parsing the argument and appending into `beam_options` I instead added it directly in `beam_options` as `"setup_file": "./setup.py"`

Comment: I've been facing the same error for a long time, I tried to implement your solution but with no success, still having same error.

Comment: Above won't work if workers are spawn in isolated network.
Setup won't be able to install pip dependencies with binaries.
@Idhem try solution proposed below

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow might have problems with installing packages that are platform locked in isolated network.
It won't be able to compile them if no network is there.
Or maybe it tries installing them but since cannot compile downloads wheels? No idea.

Still to be able to use packages like psycopg2 (binaries), or google-cloud-secret-manager (no binaries BUT dependencies have binaries), you need to install everything that has no binaries (none-any) AND no dependencies with binaries, by requirements.txt and the rest by --extra_packages param with wheel. Example:

```
--extra_packages=package_1_needed_by_2-manylinux.whl \
--extra_packages=package_2_needed_by_3-manylinux.whl \
--extra_packages=what-you-need_needing_3-none-any.whl
```