# ModuleNotFoundError while running apache beam job in dataflow using setup.py

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm having an apache beam pipeline that I used to submit to google dataflow and it runs successfully. By time, my code keep growing and I want to structure it into multiple file dependencies. That's why I referred to apache beam section [Multiple File Dependencies](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/)

When I structured my code as follows:

```
​root_dir/
  ​setup.py
  ​main.py
  __init__.py
  ​extract/
    __init__.py
    extract.py
```

When I execute it in local, it runs good, when I submit it to dataflow, I receive the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extract'
```

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="g_dataflow",
    version="0.1.0",
    install_requires=[
        'google-cloud-storage==1.42.0'
    ],
    packages=find_packages()

)
```

I tried to follow the Juliaset example by apache beam, but with no success.
Has anyone faced the same issue before?

Comment: This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227398/modulenotfounderror-in-dataflow-job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `--save_main_session` to my command line, which solved the issue